# Problems Linking Boost.filesystem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

I'm new to boost and filesystem - I am trying to link filesystem to my project without any success. Code is very simple:

```
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp> 
....
....
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)  C:\Users\user\Documents\ForamsApp\ForamsApplication\ForamsApplication\ForamClassifier.obj   ForamsApplication
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to link your binary against `boost_system` as well as `boost_filesystem`

Comment: Hey @Nim how do you do that? at the Linker menu in Visual C++?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Visual studio, but in project setting some where there should be options to control C++ build/link, in the link step add the extra libraries (path to boost libraries) and then the additional libraries - you'll need atleast the two I've listed above...

Comment: on VS the libraries are auto included. That said you need to tell the linker where to find them